# yii1 preload сайта

Tags: yii

Задача состоит в том, что при первом заходе на любую страницу сайта записывать данный get параметров в куки.

я думаю это сделать так
в конфиге     `'preload' => array('log','analytic'),`

создал компонент

```
class Analytic extends CApplicationComponent
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $_COOKIE['test'] = 'test';
    }

}
```

но почему то не работает

подскажите как сделать?

может это нужно реализовать другим способом?

Comment: Preload используется для создания объектов, используемых приложением. Проверьте, но не думаю что сессия там уже проинициализирована...

Comment: Не понял, можете пояснить?

Comment: Запустите отладку и посмотрите если сессия в вашем случае инициализировалась... Я подозреваю что нет.

Comment: впринципе не реагирует на этот компонент, даже если написать die; ему побарабану

Comment: Проверьте что у вас обозначено где этот класс располагается в main.php - например, 'components' => array('analytic' => array('class' => 'application.protected.Analytic'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный ответ дан в коментрии
Дополнительно обьявить

```
'components' => array('analytic' => array('class' => 'application.protected.Analytic'))
```